# How to save a word docx file using Apache poi. Change to saxon9he instead of saxon9pe

Tags: java, apache, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

I use the latest **Apache POI 3.13-beta1 version.** And I get an error like:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : null
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:507)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1441)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:202)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.saxonica.config.Verifier.loadLicense(Verifier.java:141)
    at com.saxonica.config.ProfessionalConfiguration.loadLicense(ProfessionalConfiguration.java:391)
    at com.saxonica.config.ProfessionalConfiguration.isLicensedFeature(ProfessionalConfiguration.java:367)
    at net.sf.saxon.IdentityTransformer.transform(IdentityTransformer.java:36)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.StreamHelper.saveXmlInStream(StreamHelper.java:80)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.ZipPartMarshaller.marshallRelationshipPart(ZipPartMarshaller.java:174)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:468)
```

My code is very simply here:

```
String filePath = "d:\\doc\\file1.docx"
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    XWPFDocument xdoc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));

    System.out.println("here I can read my file and work on it");

    String filePathOut = filePath.replace("file", "file_result");
    xdoc.write(new FileOutputStream(new File(filePathOut)));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to do a replacement and save my file back.

**EDIT 1.**
It looks like Apache poi works with our saxon9pe lib that requires a licence.
Can I set something to avoid this saxon9pe in poi and use saxon9he?

Thanks.

Comment: Apache POI should just use the default Java XML parser. What happens if you remove your customisations that change the default to be saxon?

Comment: it works when I removed it or I set up a licence to library. But this part of a project mustn't use saxon9pe. So can I change manually a default saxon parser 9pe to 9he variant?

Comment: Apache POI just asks the JVM for an XML parser, it doesn't know anything about saxon. You'll need to read the install docs for saxon and see how to tell it + the JVM which to use

Answer (score 4):

Here how I open and close docx files:

```
final XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(new File(inFileNameString)));
final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFileNameString); docx.write(out);
out.close();
docx.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works fine by default. But I have more specific parser such as saxon9pe instead of saxon9he that requires a licence